# Regex issue in R when escaping regex special characters with str_extract

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract the status -- in this case the word "Active" from this pattern:

Status\nActive\nHometown\

Using this regex: https://regex101.com/r/xegX00/1, but I cannot get it to work in R using str_extract. It does seem weird to have dual escapes, but I've tried every possible combination here and cannot get this to work. Any help appreciated!

```
mutate(status=str_extract(df, "(?<=Status\\\\n)(.*?)(?=\\\\)"))
```

Comment: What is `df` Seems thats where the problem lies

Comment: Newline (`\n`) doesn't need to be escaped, maybe try `(?<=Status\n).*(?=\n)`.

Comment: df is actually a value I've scraped from a website. I have several values piped together and using str_extract to create new variables. This is the first one that won't work.This is the content:

"Status\nActive\nHometown\nDagestan Republic, Russia\nTrains at\nFighting Eagle\nFighting style\nGrappler\nAge\n40\nHeight\n75.00\nWeight\n262.00\nOctagon Debut\nApr. 04, 2015\nReach\n76.00\nLeg reach\n41.50\nFollow him"

Comment: That is because `\n` is a newline, it is not a backslash + `n` char combination. All you need is `"(?<=Status\\n).*"` and [here is the correct test](https://regex101.com/r/xegX00/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex fails because you tested it against a wrong text.

`"Status\nActive\nHometown"` is a *string literal* that denotes (defines, represents) the following *plain text*:

```
Status
Active
Hometown
```

**In regular expression testers, you need to test against plain text!**

To match a newline, you can use `"\n"` (i.e. a line feed char, an LF char), or `"\\n"`, a regex escape that also matches a line feed char.

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
x <- "Status\nActive\nHometown\n"
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=Status\\n).*") ## => [1] "Active"
## or
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=Status\n).*")  ## => [1] "Active"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/C93IUy) and a [correct regex test](https://regex101.com/r/xegX00/2).

Note you do not need an `\n` at the end of the pattern, as in an ICU regex flavor (used in R `stringr` regex methods), the `.` pattern matches any chars other than line break chars, so it is OK to just use `.*` to match the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` in base R -

```
x <- "Status\nActive\nHometown\n"
sub('.*Status\n(.*?)\n.*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "Active"
```

If you want to use `stringr`, here is a suggestion with `str_match` which avoids using lookahead regex

```
stringr::str_match(x, 'Status\n(.*)\n')[, 2]
#[1] "Active"
```